# get values from 3d arr by indexes stored in two 1d arr with different dimensions numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array of values in this dimensions:

```
(3,m,n)
```

I have  Two 1D arrays  where  every item in one arr: `i`   and another arr: `j` is index information: like `(i,j)` index In 3d array : `3,i,j`

For example:

```
(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 637, 638, 639]), array([127, 128, 129, ...,   0,   0,   0]))
```

So I need to get 3D array with -dimensions: `(3,k,l)`- with this values based on two 1D indexes; 
fastest as possible

I can make example if somebody needs

Comment: Check out `np.ix_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [39]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)                                     
In [40]: i, j = np.array([0,2]), np.array([1,0,0])
```

We need to array `i` and `j` so they broadcast against each other to index a (2,3) block, or with the initial dimension a (3,2,3) block.  `np.ix_` is handy tool for doing this, though it isn't hard to do 'by-hand'.

```
In [41]: idx = np.ix_(np.arange(3),i,j)                                         
In [42]: idx                                                                    
Out[42]: 
(array([[[0]],

        [[1]],

        [[2]]]), 
 array([[[0],
         [2]]]), 
 array([[[1, 0, 0]]]))

In [43]: arr[idx]                                                               
Out[43]: 
array([[[ 1,  0,  0],
        [ 5,  4,  4]],

       [[ 9,  8,  8],
        [13, 12, 12]],

       [[17, 16, 16],
        [21, 20, 20]]])
In [44]: _.shape                                                                
Out[44]: (3, 2, 3)
```

Note the shapes of the arrays produced by `ix_`:

```
In [45]: [i.shape for i in idx]                                                 
Out[45]: [(3, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 3)]
```

Using that as a guide, I could also do the indexing with:

```
arr[:, i[None,:,None], j[None,None,:]]
```